# 1 SET statement for multiple variables like declare statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to set all variables with one set statment, like you can with a declare statement?

For example:

```
   Declare @Test VARCHAR(10),
                @Test2 VARCHAR(10),
                @Test3 INT

        SET @Test = 'test'
        SET @Test2 = 'Test2'
        SET @Test3 = 1
```

Where I want to do something like the below, but the below does not work:

```
Set @Test = 'test',
    @Test2 = 'Test2',
    @Test3 = 3
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Instead of `SET`, use `SELECT`.

```
SELECT @Test = 'test',
       @Test2 = 'Test2',
       @Test3 = 3;
```

Here's a [great article on SET vs SELECT in SQL Server / TSQL](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/differences_between_set_and_select.htm).